# Output structure-array from c-mex s-functions

Tags: matlab, simulink, bus, s-function

I am trying to output the following structure via a bus-object in simulink from my c-mex s-function. The following code-snippet is from my main matlab-file and if I run this script, the `slBus1`-simulink-bus-object is created and placed in the matlab-workspace.

```
a.b = 7;
a.c = 5;
a.e(1).d = 1;
a.e(2).d = 2;
a.e(3).d = 3;

bus1 = Simulink.Bus.createObject(a);
```

I used the simulink s-function-builder to create the follwing code for outputting the structure `a` (or `slBus1`) via a simulink-bus. The simulink-model looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, all outout-ports from the bus-selector-block have strangely the dimension [1x1], but the substructure `e` should have the dimension [3x1]. This behaviour also occurs if I use a indexing in my main-strucure, like:

```
a(1).b = 1;
a(2).b = 2;
a(3).b = 3;
```

I will only get `a(1).b` from the simulink bus-output.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this? I didnt find anything about this in the documentation or elsewhere in the internet. Thanks!

```
 /*
 * File: test_build.c
 *
 *
  *
  *   --- THIS FILE GENERATED BY S-FUNCTION BUILDER: 3.0 ---
  *
  *   This file is an S-function produced by the S-Function
  *   Builder which only recognizes certain fields.  Changes made
  *   outside these fields will be lost the next time the block is
  *   used to load, edit, and resave this file. This file will be overwritten
  *   by the S-function Builder block. If you want to edit this file by hand, 
  *   you must change it only in the area defined as:  
  *
  *        %%%-SFUNWIZ_defines_Changes_BEGIN
  *        #define NAME 'replacement text' 
  *        %%% SFUNWIZ_defines_Changes_END
  *
  *   DO NOT change NAME--Change the 'replacement text' only.
  *
  *   For better compatibility with the Simulink Coder, the
  *   "wrapper" S-function technique is used.  This is discussed
  *   in the Simulink Coder's Manual in the Chapter titled,
  *   "Wrapper S-functions".
  *
  *  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * | See matlabroot/simulink/src/sfuntmpl_doc.c for a more detailed template |
  *  ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 * Created: Sun Mar  5 17:15:44 2017
 * 
 *
 */

#define S_FUNCTION_LEVEL 2
#define S_FUNCTION_NAME test_build
/*<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
/* %%%-SFUNWIZ_defines_Changes_BEGIN --- EDIT HERE TO _END */
#define NUM_INPUTS           0

#define NUM_OUTPUTS          1
/* Output Port  0 */
#define OUT_PORT_0_NAME      y0
#define OUTPUT_0_WIDTH       1
#define OUTPUT_DIMS_0_COL    1
#define OUTPUT_0_DTYPE       real_T
#define OUTPUT_0_COMPLEX     COMPLEX_NO
#define OUT_0_FRAME_BASED    FRAME_NO
#define OUT_0_BUS_BASED      1
#define OUT_0_BUS_NAME       slBus1
#define OUT_0_DIMS           1-D
#define OUT_0_ISSIGNED        1
#define OUT_0_WORDLENGTH      8
#define OUT_0_FIXPOINTSCALING 1
#define OUT_0_FRACTIONLENGTH  3
#define OUT_0_BIAS            0
#define OUT_0_SLOPE           0.125

#define NPARAMS              0

#define SAMPLE_TIME_0        INHERITED_SAMPLE_TIME
#define NUM_DISC_STATES      0
#define DISC_STATES_IC       [0]
#define NUM_CONT_STATES      0
#define CONT_STATES_IC       [0]

#define SFUNWIZ_GENERATE_TLC 1
#define SOURCEFILES "__SFB__"
#define PANELINDEX           6
#define USE_SIMSTRUCT        0
#define SHOW_COMPILE_STEPS   0                   
#define CREATE_DEBUG_MEXFILE 0
#define SAVE_CODE_ONLY       0
#define SFUNWIZ_REVISION     3.0
/* %%%-SFUNWIZ_defines_Changes_END --- EDIT HERE TO _BEGIN */
/*<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
#include "simstruc.h"

typedef struct {
  real_T d;
} e;

typedef struct {
  real_T b;
  real_T c;
  e e;
} slBus1;

/*
* Code Generation Environment flag (simulation or standalone target).
 */
static int_T isSimulationTarget;
/*  Utility function prototypes. */
static int_T GetRTWEnvironmentMode(SimStruct *S);
/* Macro used to check if Simulation mode is set to accelerator */
#define isDWorkPresent !(ssRTWGenIsCodeGen(S) && !isSimulationTarget)


/*====================*
 * S-function methods *
 *====================*/
/* Function: mdlInitializeSizes ===============================================
 * Abstract:
 *   Setup sizes of the various vectors.
 */
static void mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S)
{

    DECL_AND_INIT_DIMSINFO(outputDimsInfo);
    ssSetNumSFcnParams(S, NPARAMS);
     if (ssGetNumSFcnParams(S) != ssGetSFcnParamsCount(S)) {
     return; /* Parameter mismatch will be reported by Simulink */
     }

    ssSetNumContStates(S, NUM_CONT_STATES);
    ssSetNumDiscStates(S, NUM_DISC_STATES);

    if (!ssSetNumInputPorts(S, NUM_INPUTS)) return;

    if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S, NUM_OUTPUTS)) return;

  /* Register slBus1 datatype for Output port 0 */

  #if defined(MATLAB_MEX_FILE)
    if (ssGetSimMode(S) != SS_SIMMODE_SIZES_CALL_ONLY)
    {
      DTypeId dataTypeIdReg;
      ssRegisterTypeFromNamedObject(S, "slBus1", &dataTypeIdReg);
      if(dataTypeIdReg == INVALID_DTYPE_ID) return;
        ssSetOutputPortDataType(S,0, dataTypeIdReg);
    }
    #endif

    ssSetBusOutputObjectName(S, 0, (void *) "slBus1");
    ssSetOutputPortWidth(S, 0, OUTPUT_0_WIDTH);
    ssSetOutputPortComplexSignal(S, 0, OUTPUT_0_COMPLEX);
    ssSetBusOutputAsStruct(S, 0,OUT_0_BUS_BASED);
    ssSetOutputPortBusMode(S, 0, SL_BUS_MODE);
    if (ssRTWGenIsCodeGen(S)) {
       isSimulationTarget = GetRTWEnvironmentMode(S);
    if (isSimulationTarget==-1) {
       ssSetErrorStatus(S, " Unable to determine a valid code generation environment mode");
       return;
     }
       isSimulationTarget |= ssRTWGenIsModelReferenceSimTarget(S);
    }

    /* Set the number of dworks */
    if (!isDWorkPresent) {
      if (!ssSetNumDWork(S, 0)) return;
    } else {
      if (!ssSetNumDWork(S, 1)) return;
    }


   if (isDWorkPresent) {

    /*
     * Configure the dwork 0 (y0BUS)
     */
#if defined(MATLAB_MEX_FILE)

    if (ssGetSimMode(S) != SS_SIMMODE_SIZES_CALL_ONLY) {
      DTypeId dataTypeIdReg;
      ssRegisterTypeFromNamedObject(S, "slBus1", &dataTypeIdReg);
      if (dataTypeIdReg == INVALID_DTYPE_ID) return;
      ssSetDWorkDataType(S, 0, dataTypeIdReg);
    }

#endif

    ssSetDWorkUsageType(S, 0, SS_DWORK_USED_AS_DWORK);
    ssSetDWorkName(S, 0, "y0BUS");
    ssSetDWorkWidth(S, 0, DYNAMICALLY_SIZED);
    ssSetDWorkComplexSignal(S, 0, COMPLEX_NO);
}
    ssSetNumSampleTimes(S, 1);
    ssSetNumRWork(S, 0);
    ssSetNumIWork(S, 0);
    ssSetNumPWork(S, 0);
    ssSetNumModes(S, 0);
    ssSetNumNonsampledZCs(S, 0);

    /* Take care when specifying exception free code - see sfuntmpl_doc.c */
    ssSetOptions(S, (SS_OPTION_EXCEPTION_FREE_CODE |
                     SS_OPTION_USE_TLC_WITH_ACCELERATOR | 
             SS_OPTION_WORKS_WITH_CODE_REUSE));
}

/* Function: mdlInitializeSampleTimes =========================================
 * Abstract:
 *    Specifiy  the sample time.
 */
static void mdlInitializeSampleTimes(SimStruct *S)
{
    ssSetSampleTime(S, 0, SAMPLE_TIME_0);
    ssSetOffsetTime(S, 0, 0.0);
}


#define MDL_START  /* Change to #undef to remove function */
#if defined(MDL_START)
  /* Function: mdlStart =======================================================
   * Abstract:
   *    This function is called once at start of model execution. If you
   *    have states that should be initialized once, this is the place
   *    to do it.
   */
static void mdlStart(SimStruct *S)
{
    /* Bus Information */
    slDataTypeAccess *dta = ssGetDataTypeAccess(S);
    const char *bpath = ssGetPath(S);
    DTypeId eId = ssGetDataTypeId(S, "e");
    DTypeId slBus1Id = ssGetDataTypeId(S, "slBus1");

    int_T *busInfo = (int_T *)malloc(6*sizeof(int_T));
    if(busInfo==NULL) {
        ssSetErrorStatus(S, "Memory allocation failure");
        return;
    }

      /* Calculate offsets of all primitive elements of the bus */

    busInfo[0] = dtaGetDataTypeElementOffset(dta, bpath,slBus1Id,0);
    busInfo[1] = dtaGetDataTypeSize(dta, bpath, ssGetDataTypeId(S, "double"));
    busInfo[2] = dtaGetDataTypeElementOffset(dta, bpath,slBus1Id,1);
    busInfo[3] = dtaGetDataTypeSize(dta, bpath, ssGetDataTypeId(S, "double"));
    busInfo[4] = dtaGetDataTypeElementOffset(dta, bpath,slBus1Id,2) +dtaGetDataTypeElementOffset(dta, bpath,eId,0);
    busInfo[5] = dtaGetDataTypeSize(dta, bpath, ssGetDataTypeId(S, "double"));
    ssSetUserData(S, busInfo);
}
#endif /*  MDL_START */

#define MDL_SET_OUTPUT_PORT_DATA_TYPE
static void mdlSetOutputPortDataType(SimStruct *S, int port, DTypeId dType)
{
    ssSetOutputPortDataType(S, 0, dType);
}

#define MDL_SET_DEFAULT_PORT_DATA_TYPES
static void mdlSetDefaultPortDataTypes(SimStruct *S)
{
   ssSetOutputPortDataType(S, 0, SS_DOUBLE);
}

#define MDL_SET_WORK_WIDTHS
#if defined(MDL_SET_WORK_WIDTHS) && defined(MATLAB_MEX_FILE)

static void mdlSetWorkWidths(SimStruct *S)
{
  /* Set the width of DWork(s) used for marshalling the IOs */
  if (isDWorkPresent) {

     /* Update dwork 0 */
     ssSetDWorkWidth(S, 0, ssGetOutputPortWidth(S, 0));

    }
}

#endif
void sete(e *out)
{
    out[0].d=1;
    out[1].d=2;   
    out[2].d=2; 
}

void test_build_Outputs_wrapper(slBus1 *y0)
{
    y0[0].b=3;
    y0[0].c=4;
    sete(&y0[0].e);
}

/* Function: mdlOutputs =======================================================
 *
*/
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    char *y0 = (char *) ssGetOutputPortSignal(S,0);

    int_T* busInfo = (int_T *) ssGetUserData(S);

    /* Temporary bus copy declarations */
    slBus1 _y0BUS;

    /*Copy input bus into temporary structure*/

    test_build_Outputs_wrapper(&_y0BUS);

    /*Copy temporary structure into output bus*/
    (void) memcpy(y0+ busInfo[0], &_y0BUS.b, busInfo[1]);
    (void) memcpy(y0+ busInfo[2], &_y0BUS.c, busInfo[3]);
    (void) memcpy(y0+ busInfo[4], &_y0BUS.e.d, busInfo[5]);
}



/* Function: mdlTerminate =====================================================
 * Abstract:
 *    In this function, you should perform any actions that are necessary
 *    at the termination of a simulation.  For example, if memory was
 *    allocated in mdlStart, this is the place to free it.
 */
static void mdlTerminate(SimStruct *S)
{
    /*Free stored bus information*/
    int_T *busInfo = (int_T *) ssGetUserData(S);
    if(busInfo!=NULL) {
      free(busInfo);
    }
}


static int_T GetRTWEnvironmentMode(SimStruct *S)
{
    int_T status;
    mxArray *plhs[1];
    mxArray *prhs[1];
    int_T err;

    /*
      * Get the name of the Simulink block diagram
    */
    prhs[0] = mxCreateString(ssGetModelName(ssGetRootSS(S)));
    plhs[0] = NULL;

    /*
      * Call "isSimulationTarget = rtwenvironmentmode(modelName)" in MATLAB
    */
    mexSetTrapFlag(1);
    err = mexCallMATLAB(1, plhs, 1, prhs, "rtwenvironmentmode");
    mexSetTrapFlag(0);
    mxDestroyArray(prhs[0]);

    /*
     * Set the error status if an error occurred
    */
    if (err) {
        if (plhs[0]) {
            mxDestroyArray(plhs[0]);
            plhs[0] = NULL;
        }
        ssSetErrorStatus(S, "Unknow error during call to 'rtwenvironmentmode'.");
        return -1;
    }

    /*
      * Get the value returned by rtwenvironmentmode(modelName)
    */
   if (plhs[0]) {
       status = (int_T) (mxGetScalar(plhs[0]) != 0);
       mxDestroyArray(plhs[0]);
       plhs[0] = NULL;
   }

    return (status);
}

#ifdef  MATLAB_MEX_FILE    /* Is this file being compiled as a MEX-file? */
#include "simulink.c"      /* MEX-file interface mechanism */
#else
#include "cg_sfun.h"       /* Code generation registration function */
#endif
```

Comment: How did you defined slBus1? Did you specify the dimensions for the third field?

Comment: `slBus1` is automatically created by the `bus1 = Simulink.Bus.createObject(a)`-command. I did not specify the dimensions by hand. I just used the s-function builder for the exisiting structure/bus-object.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. Have you checked the Dimensions property of the bus Elements created for you in slBus1 and its child element bus.